# Point-to-point T1 over fiber using media converters

Tags: cisco, point-to-point, media-conversion

So I recently purchased some media converters to take our T1 lines, that currently run over copper stretch far past it's limits, over some new fiber we had installed. They didn't work. I am a novice with T1 connections so I'm not sure what the issue is.

After some research it looks like there are special media converters that I need to use for the T1 lines. Is this accurate? Is there no way for me to get these media converters to work? Maybe a switch with VLAN ports? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the media converter you've bought are specifically marketed as T1 Fiber Extender/Converter, it won't work.

T1 isn't Ethernet even if it's using RJ-45.

Regular media converter are for Copper Ethernet to Fiber Ethernet, not T1 signals

A quick google search with "t1 fiber copper converter" will yield various manufacturers that are making the bona fide converter you need.

Comment: Thanks. My researched turned up the same thing but I was hoping for a way out.

Comment: @Securus the obvious question would be what are these T1s being used for? if it's just point to point IP data then it should be easy enough to reconfigure the routers to put that traffic on an ethernet port. If it's something else then things may be harder.